# Difference between "creating the Feature branch from master" and difference between "creating feature branch from Release Branch"

Tags: git, github, svn, bitbucket, branching-and-merging

i have created release branch from master

1, what is Difference between "creating the Feature_1 branch from master" and difference between "creating feature_1 branch from Release Branch".

2,if i create from feature_1 branch directly from master does all changes moves to master without applying to release branch?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1, what is Difference between "creating the Feature_1 branch from master" and difference between "creating feature_1 branch from Release Branch".

If you have no commit inconsistency between `master` and Release Branch, by inconsistency I mean, if no new commits have been done on either of those branches after checking out Release Branch, there is no difference then.

> 2,if i create from feature_1 branch directly from master does all changes moves to master without applying to release branch?

I am not entirely sure what you meant by this question, but I'm pretty sure none of the changes/commits will go anywhere, neither `master` nor `feature_1` branch, until you either raise PR against them or cherry-pick the commits on both branches explicitly.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

1, what is Difference between "creating the Feature_1 branch from master" and difference between "creating feature_1 branch from Release Branch".

If you have no commit inconsistency between master and Release Branch, by inconsistency I mean, if no new commits have been done on either of those branches after checking out Release Branch, there is no difference then.

2,if i create from feature_1 branch directly from master does all changes moves to master without applying to release branch?

I am not entirely sure what you meant by this question, but I'm pretty sure none of the changes/commits will go anywhere, neither master nor feature_1 branch, until you either raise PR against them or cherry-pick the commits on both branches explicitly.